# Blackberry access to administrative API without BES

Tags: blackberry

I have to disable mass storage. Can I do this with administrative API without using BES?

Comment: You want to do this via an app on the device?  What kind of app are you developing, java, webworks, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

No. 
Administrative api is used for BES so if you want to control the device you need the bes server otherwise you have to built custom application.